# GWT Image path capture using FileUpload and then storing the image as Blob in MySQL

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, gwtupload

I am using Eclipse Juno, GWT, Java and am a novice.

Can anyone please point me to a good tutorial for using FileUpload to capture the path of an image, display the image in the View and then storing the image as a Blob in MySQL. I have found a very good tutorial for GAE. However, I am not using GAE.

What I am looking at is:

1. Using a change handler on the FileUpload to trigger the capture of the image's path and display the image. However, I understand that this requires a Server side call and that the image needs to be temporarily stored (or does it need to be stored in the DB at this point, read from the DB to display and the row deleted if not needed?).
2. Using a Button click event to store the image as a Blob in MySQL.

Thanks for your help,

Glyn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, the main thing is to develop a servlet to get the file and put it anywere in the server (filesystem, database, etc). Additionally you have to offer a servlet to return the file to the client to display it.

I would use [gwtupload](https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload), which makes all the process pretty simpler. Take a look to the example in the gwtupload [GettingStarted](https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/wiki/GwtUpload_GettingStarted). It does almost everything you need except that it stores the file in a folder and maintain a list in memory to get a file given it's client id. The only thing you have to modify is the part where the servlet stores the file in a folder (`executeAction`), and the part where the servlet returns the file to the client (`getUploadedFile`), and change it to store/read the file into mysql.

Using gwtupload, you have other nice features like the ability to customize the FileUpload button, progress bar, multiple uploads etc.

Comment: Thank you both. I have had alook at this and it looks like what I need. Unfortunately I have suddenly become very busy in work (this is a side project for Scouts). However, I will get back to you with my results, especially as there is no other tutorial for DB, so other will hopefully find some useful information here. I am very sorry however it may be several weeks before I can get back to this. I very much appreciate your help. Regards, Glyn.

Comment: OK my first problem is including the required libraries. The more I read the more confused I become. Let us use the commons-fileupload as an example. I downloaded this and it has a number of folders and files in it. Do I just copy the file "commons-fileupload-1.3.jar" to the folder "Eclipse/Workspace/AwardTracker/war/WEB-INF/lib"? Is it that simple? Thanks, Glyn

Comment: if you use maven just include gwtupload dependency and you will have all dependencies resolved. Otherwise download gwtupload, commons-io, commons-fileupload and log4j, and include them in your classpath.

Comment: Hi, this is where I have my problem. I read everything and they say copy or include. However, where do I copy to or how do I include? I copied  "commons-fileupload-1.3.jar" to the folder "Eclipse/Workspace/AwardTracker/war/WEB-INF/lib" and it does not show up in Eclipse. So obviously I need to run something else to ïnclude" it. I went into Eclipse, right clicked the project, clicked on Properties, selected "Java Build path", Libraries, ''Ádd JARs..'navigated to "AwardTracker/war/WEB-INF/lib" but "commons-fileupload-1.3.jar" was not displayed. Regards, Glyn

Comment: Refresh eclipse project to read the files added to the lib folder from command-line or external program (project -> refresh). Add new libraries to project (project -> properties -> build path -> libraries -> add jars)

Comment: Hi Manolo, I selected the project and then "Project" from the top menu and there was no "Refresh" option. I then selected "project -> properties -> java build path -> libraries -> add jars" and there was no option to add libraries. I am getting more and more confused. Regards, Glyn

Comment: #1 Right click on the project -> refresh.  #2 once you are in the add jars dialog go to the lib folder where you have the libraries.

Comment: Hi Manolo, I really greatly appreciate your persistence in helping me. This worked! Thank you very much. Regards, Glyn.

Comment: My pleasure. So select the question it it's the correct answer.

Comment: Sorry, I have not finished yet (due to other commitments - this is in my spare time). However, I will try to get it done ASAP and give you a more than well deserved tick. Once again thank you for your help and patience. Regards, Glyn

Comment: Hi Manolo, Thank you for all your help. I have not quite go this working. However, I have got it to a stage where I should open another question and give you your more than deserved tick. I greatly appreciate all your help. Regards, Glyn

Answer (score 1):

I think you may try to use gwtupload - https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/